# Material design lite live checkbox load

Tags: javascript, jquery, checkbox, material-design-lite

In my project I'm use the mdl framework and jquery for ajax. Now I create index page and page.html. In index I have complete page structure and in page.html view like this:

```
  <span class="mdl-list__item-primary-content">
    <span>
      <label class="mdl-checkbox mdl-js-checkbox mdl-js-ripple-effect" for="checkbox-1">
        <input type="checkbox" id="checkbox-1" class="mdl-checkbox__input" {{complete}}>
      </label>
    </span>
    <span>
      {{name}}
    </span>
    <span class="mdl-list__item-text-body">
      {{name2}}
    </span>
  </span>
```

But that loaded page, load standard checkbox. I try to use js code like this:

```
document.querySelector('.mdl-js-checkbox').MaterialCheckbox()
or
document.querySelector('.mdl-js-checkbox').MaterialCheckbox.check()
or
$('.mdl-js-checkbox').MaterialCheckbox
```

and other a lot of method but anyone not work and my checkbox view like standard. Do you have any idea ?

Comment: to be clear, are you trying to "check" the `checkbox` using js?

Comment: No, My checkbox view like standard browser checkbox, but I need to view it like material design checkbox, like this: https://codepen.io/anon/pen/RgPbxr
  When I use checkbox in index everythink work okey but it not work when loaded via ajax.